# Responsive cursor animation

Tags: javascript, animation, web, cursor

Animation of the cursor interacts with objects on the page. Example [page](https://kalpa.parmigiani.com/en#).
Is it some kind of plug-in? Which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about possible plugins they're using, however, they aren't changing the cursor but just putting a div (the circle) at the position of the mouse. They also possibly have a `onhover` event which changes the size of the div. You don't need a library to implement that.

Comment: Thank you) I wanted to make sure it was a plugin. But now it is clear that it is necessary to write by hand